# Find the number of solutions to the equation.... Someone please explain how they got this answer?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I don't understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

By [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two), the number of non-negative solutions of 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=n:=22-x_5$$
with $k:=4$ unknowns $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and with $x_5\in\{5,10,15,20\}$ is
$$\binom{n+k-1}{n}=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{22-x_5+3}{3}=\binom{25-x_5}{3}.$$
By letting $x_5=5,10,15,20$ we find four binomial coefficients that have to be added by the [addition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum).

Comment: Where did the 3 even come from?

Comment: I just don't understand how stars and bars applies to this problem.

Comment: Did you READ the suggested wiki-page?

Comment: @Stuy Is it clear? Any further doubt?